# Where did the Robert Frost Quote "If we couldn't laugh, we would all go insane" come from?

Tags: quote-source, robert-frost

I have found numerous sources that attribute the quote "If we couldn't laugh we would all go insane" to Robert Frost but for the life of me, I cannot find when / where he actually said / wrote it.

Comment: Many other sources attribute it to Jimmy Buffett. [Buffett really did use that line.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2_lU3adj5k) I have no idea if Frost also used it, and if so who stole it from whom.

Comment: @user24222 As Frost was born in 1874 and Buffett in 1946, I think it likely that Frost said it first. There are so many sources that attribute it to Frost, but with no when or where details...

Comment: @Livrecache If Frost said it at all, he has priority. Do you have any reason to believe he did? Those sites that attribute it to him without giving details count for nothing. If they find a saying they like, and they don't know the source, they will attribute it to a random notable, such as Franklin, Lincoln, or Einstein.

Comment: In general, you can assume that *any* quote you read on the Internet is horseshit. This doesn't even sound like Frost.

Comment: I agree with Joshua Engel: it's too dumb to be Frost.  Google books didn't know of *anybody* writing this until about 2000, then Bill Watterson (author of *Calvin and Hobbes*) said something like it, then in about 2005 Buffet used it and in about 2010 people began attributing it to Frost.

Comment: @kimchilover Huh? The [Jimmy Buffett song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nw0YHCn6GTU) with that line was released in **1977** not 2005.

Comment: I stand corrected. I meant, a **Google Books** search got no hits until more recently.  Presumably because GB is an inexact tool, and because people didn't  refer to Buffet's lyrics in books until more recently.  I used Google book as a tool because I thought that *if* Frost was the real author, the sequence of words might show up in a book written during his lifetime.  (Frost being a book writer, and the subject of books, you know.)

Comment: @kimchilover I'm pretty sure that when that hit song came out in 1977, if that line really was from Robert Frost, *somebody would have said something about it*, and it would have shown up in Google Books long before 2000.

Comment: I agree completely.  If Frost wrote it, it would have been mentioned in a book (such as, one by Frost).  GB doesn't show any thing like that, so it's reasonable to conclude the Frost connection is bogus.

Comment: @kimchilover Maybe not by Robert Frost himself (who died in 1963) but surely one of his heirs or publishers or fans would have said something. Haven't you got enough to write an answer?

Comment: @JoshuaEngel Horseradish, rather.

Comment: @user14111 - to paraphrase one or the other of them, it's a thin line between Robert Frost and Jimmy Buffett... :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can't prove a negative, but I will (tentatively) declare

### Frost didn't say that

As evidence, I present yearbooks.

No, seriously, my evidence is going to be mostly yearbooks here. High school/university students like cynical, smart-sounding, pithy, contrary, or otherwise amusing quotes to put next to their yearbook pictures. I guessed that they'd like this quote and went searching [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/)'s text-contents storage to find some yearbooks with this quote.

As expected, a bunch of the results of [the search](https://archive.org/search.php?query=%22If%20we%20couldn%27t%20laugh%20we%20would%20all%20go%20insane%22&sin=TXT) were yearbooks. (Lots of yearbooks have been scanned into the archive, people like saving them). The earliest year with any results for the phrase was [1978, with 3 hits](https://archive.org/search.php?query=%22If%20we%20couldn%27t%20laugh%20we%20would%20all%20go%20insane%22&sin=TXT&and%5B%5D=year%3A%221978%22).

- Result 1: the [1978 Greensboro College yearbook](https://archive.org/details/echo1978gree/page/114/mode/2up?q=If+we+couldn%27t+laugh+we+would+all+go+insane). The phrase pops up in a rendition of the lyrics to [the Jimmy Buffet song](https://genius.com/Jimmy-buffett-changes-in-latitudes-changes-in-attitudes-lyrics). The students must've really liked the music; the yearbook's [title page](https://archive.org/details/echo1978gree/mode/2up) is designed to be obviously reminiscent of the [album cover](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/97/Buffettchanges.jpg).
- Result 2: the [1978 Columbia University Department of Nursing yearbook](https://archive.org/details/departmentofnurs1978colu/page/24/mode/2up?q=If+we+couldn%27t+laugh+we+would+all+go+insane). Someone used this line as their yearbook quote, and attributed it to "J. Buffet".
- Result 3: the [1978 Wachusett Regional High School yearbook](https://archive.org/details/wachusettregiona1978unse/mode/2up?q=If+we+couldn%27t+laugh+we+would+all+go+insane). Someone used this line as their yearbook quote, and attributed it to "J. B.".

All of that fits with young adults getting obsessed with a song and referencing the new cool lines it in their yearbooks. If the quote was from Frost, and around before then, I would expect students in prior years to have used this quote in their yearbooks.

To be more sure, I searched for this quote alongside "frost". This should pick up any archived version of the quote when it's attributed to Robert Frost. With a lot of false positives, annoyingly. All of the results attributing it to Frost were much more recent: [2015](https://archive.org/details/belmonthighschoo2015belm/page/38/mode/2up?q=If+we+couldn%27t+laugh+we+would+all+go+insane+frost), [2011](https://archive.org/details/wachusettregiona2011unse/page/56/mode/2up?q=If+we+couldn%27t+laugh+we+would+all+go+insane+frost), [2010](https://archive.org/details/the-great-book-of-best-quotes-of-all-time/page/144/mode/2up?q=If+we+couldn%27t+laugh+we+would+all+go+insane+Robert+frost). (There was even one attributing it to James Taylor!)

This fits with [@kimchi lover's comment](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/5535/where-did-the-robert-frost-quote-if-we-couldnt-laugh-we-would-all-go-insane#comment10881_5535) (bolding by me, italics by them):

> I agree with Joshua Engel: it's too dumb to be Frost. Google books didn't know of *anybody* writing this until about 2000, then Bill Watterson (author of *Calvin and Hobbes*) said something like it, then in about 2005 Buffet used it and **in about 2010 people began attributing it to Frost.**

If anyone can point to where Frost said this, I'd be happy to admit to being wrong, but seeing how long this question's been up I think that's unlikely.

Conclusion: as the snarky young adults can show us, this quote first showed up as a Jimmy Buffet lyric, and was only decades later misattributed to Robert Frost.

Answer (score 0):

Frost certainly did not say it or write it. I read all his published poems, and much else besides, in researching his life and work over a period of more than a decade. It’s an original line (if not an original idea) from Jimmy Buffet.